# iPhone Wireless Sync and iTunes remote management

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

I've managed to finally get wireless sync working between my iPhone and main server in my house. Now I'm trying to manage what syncs to my iPhone from the device itself rather than having to do it from iTunes on my machine. I checked out the Remote app, and while that hooks up to the library, I'm not able to select anything to sync.

Is this even possible, or if I want to add any media from my library to my device do I need to select it in iTunes directly and then launch the wireless sync?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you must be on your computer to select which media you want transferred to the device. After manually dragging media to your device or setting up what should be transferred under the correct tabs (i.e Music, Videos, etc.), you must then initiate a sync. I believe wifi sync to be, in short, the same as a USB sync, only over wifi instead of USB, minus a few features such as restoring a backup.

One note - you have probably already figured this out, but after your phone is plugged into USB, don't eject it, just unplug it. Wifi sync will work properly if just unplugged and not ejected.